# Listview: Align Column Header Separately from Items in Column?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I want to align my Listview **column headers** like this:

**Legend:** (C) = Center Alignment, (L) = Left Alignment

```
(L) Column Header 1 | (C) Header 2 | (C) Header 3 | (L) Header 4
```

All **Items** in the Listview are then Left Aligned (L)

I'm aware of the `.TextAlign` property when adding/editing columns, however, whatever that is aligned to also aligns the items in that column the same, (i.e. the column headers I set to (C) will also have all items in those columns center aligned, which I don't want.)

Is this do-able?

Comment: Can you post some of ur code - to understand ur problem better.

Comment: There's no code really to post, lol. Everything's in the question; I used the columns' `.TextAlign` properties to layout the columns like that, now I just want all the items I add to the listview to be Left Aligned.

Comment: Pretty much no.  The LV Column doesnt provide separate properties for HeaderTextAlign and ItemTextAlign.  It isnt a grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `OwnerDraw` the `ColumnHeaders`: Set `listView1.OwnerDraw = true;`

Here is an example that sets separate alignments for three `Columns`:

```
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, 
                                        DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    ColumnHeader ch = listView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
    HorizontalAlignment colHal = ch.TextAlign;
    HorizontalAlignment headHal = colHal;

    // three headers that use a different alignment than the columns :
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) headHal = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) headHal = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2) headHal = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

    SizeF size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(ch.Text, e.Font);

    float x = 
        headHal == HorizontalAlignment.Center ? ( e.Bounds.Width - size.Width ) / 2f :
        headHal == HorizontalAlignment.Right  ? ( e.Bounds.Width - size.Width ) : 0f;

    e.DrawBackground();

    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor) )
           e.Graphics.DrawString(ch.Text, e.Font, brush, 
                                 e.Bounds.X + x, 5f, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
}

private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}

private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}
```

You may need to play with the `5f` vertical offset depending on your font..

[image: listViewHeaders]